# Update SVN Repository on server remotely

Tags: svn, version-control, ftp

One of my clients has an SVN repository on an internal network. The files are then committed to the repository and then copied manually from the internal server to an external server through FTP.

From the external server (which is the testing/production environment) we **can not** access the internal repository.

So my question is how would you recommend I automatically update the external testing/production server when I can not access the repository.

I was thinking of writing/using a tool that connects to the external server via FTP, deletes everything, then uploads the latest files from the local internal network.

If I could access the repository from the server I would use the [update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) command but as this is not possible I'm looking for an alternative.

Is there a way I can do this with the SVN command line tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build repository-mirror on the host, reachable from Testing and MainRepo, using [SVNSync](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt)

But for

> how would you recommend I automatically update the external testing/production server when I can not access the repository

task:

**correct** solution will be update **not** from your side, but **from repository**, as part of post-commit hook (and FTP-only update is rather hard work /contrary to SSH/)

Comment: SVNSync is exactly what I was looking for (I think). Unfortunately it's a Windows server and we can not install any software on the machines.